# Get list of days in the week that reflect locale in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, locale

I have this function that returns days of the week:

```js
var SEPARATOR = '  ';
function week_days(lang) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
        var d = new Date(1970, 1, 1 + i);
        result.push(d.toLocaleString(lang, {weekday: 'short'}).substring(0, 2));
    }
    return result.join(SEPARATOR);
}

console.log("en-us", week_days("en-us"))
console.log("pl-pl", week_days("pl-pl"))
```

but it's fixed and starts from Sunday like in the US locale. But in the Polish locale week starts from Monday. There are probably languages that use one or the other.

I can use `new Date(1970, 1, 2 + i);` and it will work, but how I can make it based on Locale? (e.g. `window.navigator.language`).

Comment: `lang` seems to control this. What about passing a different lang?

Comment: @evolutionxbox You don't understand lang is locale, I'm asking how to get a proper date that will give me the first day. The problem is `d` variable, not lang.

Comment: @Phil I'm showing the function that I use. I can delete that code if you want. The code only shows the problem, since I don't know any other way to get a day of the week in JavaScript. if you know better way please share.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your question initially. Was just about to link you to the same ecma402 issue you found

Comment: [Intl.Locale.prototype.weekInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/weekInfo) returns an object including a `firstDay` property. [proposal]

Comment: @pilchard that [browser compatibility though](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/weekInfo#browser_compatibility) 

Comment: True, but the relevant proposal.

Comment: how about defining a switch case with a variety of country codes or perhaps all the locale string possibilities and return the first day of the week. Then use that to identify the first day from the locale string and use it accordingly?

Comment: For the Intl object, "locale" does not mean location, it means language. What a person considers the first day of the week is generally independent of language and is much more aligned with cultural preferences of the local administration. In many places it's not fixed and much more a user preference, so trying to enforce a particular  cultural choice based solely on language is not sensible.

Comment: @RobG to give you an idea why I need this, I want to implement the output of the Linux `cal` command, that gives reasonable output based on the language. It's for this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ascii-calendar

Comment: Then find the linux mapping for language to first day of the week and included it as data for your package. And be prepared to offend as many people as you please. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the spec has no way of knowing this information. It's tracked here:

https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/6

This is an old issue. From the comments, it seems that there is a spec:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-locale-info

That should handle this.

Comment: In regard to ECMA-262, the days of the week are numbered 0 to 6 for Sunday to Saturday respectively. That does not mean the first day of the week is fixed as Sunday, it just means that's the indexing system used in the specification. ECMA-402 does not specify any cultural preferences for dates, it recommends using the [UNICODE CLDR project](https://cldr.unicode.org/) data for that. So "*the spec has no way of knowing this information*" is misleading, it makes no attempt at presenting the information, but it could if it wanted to by summarising data in the CLDR (which is not to say it should)

Comment: In regard to the proposed "Intl locale info", I think it's a complete waste of time. Why do people want to standardise cultural practices that change on a whim? E.g. in Saudi Arabia the "weekend" was Thu/Fri until June 2013, when it was changed to Fri/Sat. Some in the Kingdom are resistant to change so some observe Thu/Fri and others Fri/Sat. Where I live people are pretty much evenly divided in whether Sun or Mon is the first day of the week. If it matters, let users pick which day they want as the first of the week, as my OS does under regional settings.